# Periodically fetch data from API in the background and update UI

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to have an app that periodically fetches data from an API and update the UI with the fetched data.

I'm fairly new to Android development. I looked around and found out(altough I might as well be missing something) that I could use `WorkManager` to fetch the data in the background and I can periodically run it with `PeriodicWorkRequest` in the MainActivity or ViewModel.

However, my problem is that I couldn't figure out how to pass the fetched data from Worker. The data is a JSON response that contains list of objects, let's say `List<WeatherData>`. I saw that you could pass `outputData` to `Result.success()` by using key value pair with `workerDataOf` but I think this is only suitable for lightweight data and primitive types.

How can I pass this data that I fetch in the worker to update the UI? OR is there any other alternative to achieve my goal?

I want to achieve this by following best practices and keep separation concerns i.e. not using `viewModel` in the worker.

Comment: are you aware how workmanager works and what is periodic work request and how to use it? then i can explain how to get that api data into mainactivity or fragment

Comment: @Laser yeah, I think I can figure it out if you do

Answer (score 0):

So, Here is an example to have a periodic work every 15 mins(You can set your own interval).

**NOTE: minimum interval for periodic work is 15 mins. So even if you set 1 minute, the work will run every 15 mins only.**

So in below example i am calling an api in the worker class in background the setting  the api data in the fragment by converting the response into an jsonfile and then receiving the broadcast in fragment. And the api is called every 15 mins.

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding.apply {


            adapter = MainAdapter()
            viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this@FlagFragment)[MyViewModel::class.java]

            val constraints: Constraints = Constraints.Builder().apply {
                setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                setRequiresBatteryNotLow(true)
            }.build()

            notificationWorkRequest = PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(
                ApiCallWork::class.java, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES,  15, TimeUnit.MINUTES
            )

                .setConstraints(constraints)
                .build()

            WorkManager.getInstance(requireContext()).enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(
                "my_work",
                ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, notificationWorkRequest
            )
            WorkManager.getInstance(requireContext()).enqueue(notificationWorkRequest)

            recyclerView.adapter = adapter
            getObserver()

            val getList = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
                override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
                    when (intent?.action) {
                        "MyReciever" -> {
                            val name = intent.extras?.getString("list")
                            if (name != null) {
                                val data = readJsonFromInternalStorage(
                                    requireContext(),
                                    name
                                )
                                myModelList = parseJsonToModelList(data)

                                Log.d("data", myModelList.toString())
                                viewModel.setFlagList(myModelList as List<MainFlagModel>)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                  }
                }   
       
                requireActivity().registerReceiver(getList, IntentFilter("MyReciever"))                        
        }
    }
```

here is getObserver Function :

```
    private fun getObserver() {
        viewModel.flagList.observe(requireActivity()) {
            if (it.isNotEmpty()) {
                adapter.setFlagList(it)
            }
        }
    }
```

Other functions :

```
    private fun readJsonFromInternalStorage(context: Context, fileName: String): String {
        try {
            val fileInputStream = context.openFileInput(fileName)
            val stringBuilder = StringBuilder()
            val inputStreamReader = InputStreamReader(fileInputStream)
            val bufferedReader = BufferedReader(inputStreamReader)

            var line: String? = bufferedReader.readLine()
            while (line != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n")
                line = bufferedReader.readLine()
            }

            return stringBuilder.toString()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            return ""
        }
    }
```

```
    private fun parseJsonToModelList(jsonData: String): List<MainFlagModel> {
        return Gson().fromJson(jsonData, object : TypeToken<List<MainFlagModel>>() {}.type)
    }
```

**Now the worker class**

```
class ApiCallWork(private var context: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters) :
    Worker(context, workerParams) {

    private val list = ArrayList<MainFlagModel>()

    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    override fun doWork(): Result {
        var result: Result = Result.retry()
        val countDownLatch = CountDownLatch(1)
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            val response = ApiCall().getService(baseUrl)?.allFlagDetails()
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                if (response != null) {
                    result = if (response.isSuccessful) {
                        list.addAll(response.body() as List<MainFlagModel>)
                        Log.d("response", response.body().toString())
                        val intent = Intent("MyReciever")
                        intent.putExtra("list", outputData(list))
                        context.sendBroadcast(intent)

                        Result.success()
                    } else {
                        Log.d("fail", response.message().toString())
                        Result.retry()
                    }
                    countDownLatch.countDown()
                }
            }
        }

        try {
            countDownLatch.await()
        } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        return result
    }

    private fun outputData(list: ArrayList<MainFlagModel>): String {
        val name = "response.json"
        val json = Gson().toJson(list)
        Log.d("json", json)
        val outputStream: FileOutputStream

        try {
            outputStream = context.openFileOutput(name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
            outputStream.write(json.toByteArray())
            outputStream.close()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return name
    }
}
```

You can see that the data has been succesfully set

[image]

And the api is being called every 15 minutes.

**First time called**

[image: first time]

**Second time called**

[image: second time called]